# How can i batch testing several file with phpunit?

Tags: php, phpunit, batch-processing

I've several php files, which each one declare the same class name.
I want to test all of them into a single phpunit batch, but i get "Fatal error: you cannot redeclare class" :(

Anyway to do batch testing ?
Or i've to test file per file ?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a PHPUnit restriction, rather PHP - only a single class (of same name) can be loaded at a time.

Comment: Do you really need all the classes have the same name? Use namespaces to make them distinct if they must have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure to understand your problem. Yet, here's what I'm doing for batch unit testing (hoping it will help you).

For batch unit testing a .bat script with all my unit test class listed like this (run_unit_test.bat):

```
@ECHO OFF

CLS


ECHO.
ECHO FILE : AUTOMATIC_BACKUP_MANAGER_TEST.PHP
ECHO.
CALL PHPUNIT %~DP0/TEST/AUTOMATIC_BACKUP_MANAGER_TEST.PHP
ECHO.
ECHO.
```

Then I'm using Dos command (in Xampp console, not working for me in normal dos console) like the following to send the result to a text file (I use PHP to read the text file and display it).

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\PC_administration_interface\Controler/temp_unit_test.bat > C:\xampp\htdocs\PC_administration_interface\Controler/test_result.txt
```

For automatic testing, I use the task scheduler to call that script:

```
@echo off

call C:\xampp\htdocs\PC_administration_interface\Controler\launch_xampp.bat

call C:\xampp\xampp_shell.bat

cls

call C:\xampp\htdocs\PC_administration_interface\Controler\run_unit_test.bat > "C:\xampp\htdocs\PC_administration_interface\Controler\test_result.txt"
```

Here's the Launch xampp script:

```
@echo off
tasklist | find /i "xampp-control.exe" && goto :eof

start /b "xampp-control.exe" "C:\xampp\xampp-control.exe"
```

The xampp_shell script launch the command prompt with all xampp configuration (you'll have this by default if you use Xampp that is).

In the task scheduler I'm running two operations. This one two run the script (start program in program/script textbox):

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\PC_administration_interface\Controler\launch_automatic_test.bat
```

And this one to open a new tab in chrome to display the result:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

With something like this in the add argument textbox:

```
http://localhost/PC_administration_interface/view/unit_test.php?DISPLAY_RESULT=TRUE
```

Beyond that solution, you probably should use "require_once" command to be sure that the declaration is really declared only once.

Also, it is probably a good practice to declare one unit testing class for each of your class (and only include one class per file except for constant classes used to emulate enum).

Like I said, I'm not so sure to understand your problem. You might need to provide us code sample if my solution doesn't work.

Most humbly,

Jonathan Parent-Lévesque from Montreal